# How triangle options works in OTP?

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I'm new to OpenTripPlanner project. Trying to understand how the travel options are working like walk, bicycle and other options. When we are choosing Bicycle only, 
we have an Triangle option where the end user can specify the parameters like whether it is Quick or Bicycle friendly or Slop option. Based on these parameters 
i can see two different paths for the same source and destination. Please help me how it works?[image: Bicycle Friendly]
[image: Bicycle Quickly]

Comment: I have gone through the OTP docs. But i couldn't get more information.

Comment: I guess you have to look at the source code. I assume "quick" prefers routes along roads and tries to minimize the distance whereas "bicycle friendly" prefers routes along cycle ways, cycle lanes, official cycle routes and so on, possibly resulting in a longer but safer route.

Also this is offtopic for StackOverflow since it is not really a programming-related question. The official support channel seems to be https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opentripplanner-users.